# how many words can be formed using all letters in the word EXAMINATION

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

Assuming any sequence of letters is a word, how many words can we form in such a way that the first two letters are different consonants while the last two letters are vowels?

Comment: Hello new user. The [official recommendation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is to describe what you have tried so far, and to pinpoint where you are stuck exactly. That way, people will be more sympathetic to helping you!

Comment: This is a programming problem - give me twenty minutes...

Comment: My unofficial recommendation is to give the new user some time to edit this into a better question, instead of closing the question immediately.

Comment: @mistermarko not on math stackexchange, it isn't. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A beginning:

There is no single formula for this. Therefore we have to organize the different types of cases, to which then known formulas apply.

There are $11$ slots where we have to write a letter. How many choices are there for the first two letters? They are of two different types, because of the double N. How many choices are there for the last two letters. Again there are different types.

Finally we have to fill in ("permute") the seven intermediate letters. There are no restrictions, but according to the types identified before the count will be different.

Answer (score 2):

> how many words can be formed using all letters in the word EXAMINATION
>
> Assuming any sequence of letters is a word, how many words can we form in such a way that the first two letters are different consonants while the last two letters are vowels?

Assuming each letter is used only as many times as it occurs in the word.

First count the ways to place vowels and consonants, without considering identity or order within their type.

In addition to the two places on each ends, reserved for two consonants and two vowels respectively, there are seven places in the middle of the arrangement, which can hold three consonants and four vowels in $\frac{7!}{3!4!}$ ways.

$$\oplus\oplus\,\underbrace{\oplus\oplus\oplus\otimes\otimes\otimes\otimes}_{\frac{7!}{3!4!}\text{ permutations}}\,\otimes\otimes$$

Next count the ways to fill those places.

The consonants: `XMTNN`, can be arranged in $\frac{5!}{2!}-3!$ distinct permutations such that the pair of N do not simultaneously occupy the first two positions.

The vowels: `EOAAII` can be arranged in $\frac{6!}{2!2!}$ distinct permutations.  If the vowels in the last two places have to be distinct this would be $\frac{6!}{2!2!}-2\times\frac{4!}{2!}$ permutations.

Thus there are $\frac{7!}{4!3!}\!\!\left(\frac{5!}{2!}-3!\right)\!\!\left(\frac{6!}{2!2!}\right)$ ways to arrange the letters as specified.  ($340,200$)

There are $\frac{7!}{4!3!}\!\!\left(\frac{5!}{2!}-3!\right)\!\!\left(\frac{6!}{2!2!}-2\times\frac{4!}{2!}\right)$ ways if the vowels in the last two places have to be distinct. ($294,840$)

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import *

vows = ('E', 'A', 'I', 'O')
cons = ('X', 'M', 'N', 'T', 'S')
count = 0

for m in permutations(list('EXAMINATIONS')):
    #print(m)
    if m[0] != m[1] and m[0] in cons and m[1] in cons and m[10] in
        vows and m[11] in vows:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

The answer is 33868800 if the program is correct. It is very much unoptimized.

Comment: The problem with this is you also permutate when the same letter is in the middle 7, causing repetition.

Comment: Do you think the answer is wrong or is the algorithm inefficient?

Comment: You permutate even when the the same letters are in the middle. For example, E or I is not in the end, they are in the middle. There's two pairs of both letter.

Comment: I don't see any more optimization unless you convert this in C++ and and put -O3 in compiler.

Comment: NB Because there are two A's, I's and N's the same permutations are counted twice so it needs to be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, we need to consider 3 cases:

1. $N$ is in the first two letters.
2. $E$ is in the last two letters.
3. $I$ is in the last two letters.

To make it easier for my typing, let the propositions above be represented by the 3-tuple. e.g. $(T, T, T)$ means all propositions are true, $(F, F, F)$ means all propositions are false.

The following are the computations:

1. $(F, F, F)$ 
   Since $N, E, I$ are all in the middle, we have 3 pairs of repetitions. To account for repetitions, the method used for counting is $$P([n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k], n) = \dfrac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\dots n_k!}$$ Where $n$ is the number of objects overall (including repetitions). And the $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k$ are the repetition count. I will refer to this via $P([n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k], n)$ from now on. 
   The number of words when all proposition are false are then, $$C_{first}*C_{last}*C_{middle}$$$${{4}\choose{4-2}}{{6}\choose{6-2}}P([2, 2, 2], 7) = 226, 800 $$Since I've laid out all the tools you need, from now on its just cold heart  computation.
2. $(F, F, T)$ $${{4}\choose{4-2}}{{6}\choose{6-2}}P([2, 2], 7) = 453, 600 $$
3. $(F, T, F)$ $${{4}\choose{4-2}}{{6}\choose{6-2}}P([2, 2], 7) = 453, 600 $$
4. $(F, T, T)$ $${{4}\choose{4-2}}{{6}\choose{6-2}}P([2], 7) =907,200$$
5. $(T, F, F)$ $${{4}\choose{4-2}}{{6}\choose{6-2}}P([2, 2], 7) =453, 600$$
6. $(T, F, T)$ $${{4}\choose{4-2}}{{6}\choose{6-2}}P([2], 7) =907,200$$
7. $(T, T, F)$ $${{4}\choose{4-2}}{{6}\choose{6-2}}P([2], 7) =907,200$$
8. $(T, T, T)$ $${{4}\choose{4-2}}{{6}\choose{6-2}}7!=1,814,400$$

Adding them all up, we get $6,124,800$, accounting for $3$ pairs of repetition.

Comment: How do you justify the three initial cases? You realize the OP gave the word EXAMINATIONS to begin with?

Comment: @mistermarko If one of the $n$ is not in the start, then $n$ will be in the middle. If one or both of $a$ or $i$ are at the end, then $a$ and $i$ will be in the middle causing repetition. Can you elaborate further in that question?

Comment: Are you sure you're answering the question that was actually asked?

Comment: @mistermarko Yes. If you read Christian Blatter's answer, we have exactly the same idea. Plus in Computer Science sense, this is actually good since it's almost like $O(\log(n))$ with a very low constant $k$, or even $O(1)$ for similar problems.

Comment: Here's the problem: the _if_ clause is a direct translation of the OP's question but the result is totally different from yours. You should be able to give a different translation...

Comment: @mistermarko what do you mean "the if clause"? Are you talking about the "the if clause" in your program? Because I did made sure that there's no two the same consonants at start by ${{4}\choose{4-2}}$ instead of ${{5}\choose{5-2}}$. If yo are talking about the repetition, in your code you have phenomena's like these "HELLO" and "HELLO", you switched two L's at some point, because you are iterating at all permutations. Something that is not supposed to happen.

Comment: @mistermarko Can you get rid of 'S' in 'EXAMINATIONS', I'm comparing it but that seems to be giving what you're not intending.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15936/discussion-between-joeyandres-and-mistermarko).